# Preserving newline characters in data:text URI

Tags: google-chrome-extension, text-files, data-uri

I have a button in my extension that triggers the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'data:text;base64,'+btoa(data), active:false});
```

This triggers a download of my string (data), as I expected. Unfortunately, it seems to be stripping out newline characters.

I have tried other encoding methods, including utf-8 and the `encodeUri()` function. I also tried switching the mimetype to `data:text/plain`, but that simply opens in a new tab (with the correct newline characters) instead of downloading.

Is there a way to encode my text so that newline characters are preserved? If not, is there a different method for triggering file downloads in the browser?

*edit*

I have discovered that the newlines do appear in some text editors. Previously, I was using notepad, which did not recognize the newline characters from chrome, but my other text editor (notepad++) does seem to recognize them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommended solution is to not use Notepad, because it does not recognize non-Windows line formats. If you still want to be able to use Notepad with your output, [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all line feeds (`0x0A`) with carriage return+line feed pairs (`0x0D 0x0A`).

```js
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'data:text;base64,' + btoa(data.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n')),
    active: false
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about \r. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For all who try to preserve newline characters in a data URI without base64 encryption: 
**this is not possible**, you have to use base64 encoding.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it is possible to have newline characters without base64-encoding via URL-encoded URLs. For example: `data:text/html,<pre>a%0A%0Db</pre>`

Comment: Also, base64 is encoding, not encryption.

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer. The question was about text/plain, NOT text/html. text/plain does NOT support newline chars, you must base64 encode it.

Comment: @RobW It should be `%0D%0A`. That seems to work.