# Newline characters in CSV Data URI not showing up

Tags: csv, newline, data-uri

I have a CSV data

```
column1,column2,column3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
```

I have it as a Jade variable, which is as good as interpolated string as a whole in the HTML, and I make it available for download via `a` link in Data URI format

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var data = 'column1,column2,column3\n\rdata1,data2,data3\n\rdata1,data2,data3';
link.href = 'data:text/csv,' + data;
```

```html
<a id="link" download="data.csv">download</a>
```

I've used Javascript to insert data here for demo, but I'm actually using Jade on server side: (I don't think this makes any different though..)

```
a(href="data:text/csv,#{data.replace(/[\r\n]/, '\r\n')}" download="data.csv") Download
```

The problem is the newline character isn't working. When I download the file it doesn't have the newline characters.

In fact wiki says

> [In Mozilla Firefox 5, Google Chrome 17, and IE 9 (released June, 2011), encoded data **must not contain newlines**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#CSS)

[This another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532900/preserving-newline-characters-in-datatext-uri), if I'm not misunderstanding, did state that it's possible.

Is it really not possible to have newline for CSV download in Data URI format, or is there a way that I may have missed?

Answer (score 4):

Nice question asked a long time ago :) I suffered from this problem today as well. For me it works if I URL encode the CSV. So that newline characters "\n" and/or "\r" become "%0A" and "%0D"

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var data = 'column1,column2,column3\n\rdata1,data2,data3\n\rdata1,data2,data3';
data = encodeURI(data);
link.href = 'data:text/csv,' + data;
```

Comment: As good as using encodeURI(...) one can encode the CSV as base64: ````  var data = btoa(data); link.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + data; ````