# The data is written in one line when a file is downloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i click on a button a file should be downloaded with the `content` inside it:

```
downloadFile: function(name, content) {
        const a = document.body.appendChild(
            document.createElement('a')
        );
        a.download = name + ".txt";
        a.href = `data:text, ${content.trim()}`;
        a.click();
    }
```

Currently what the code is doing is writing all `contents` into one line of a file, but I would like it to get written as is, for example, if `contents` is :

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
```

then it should be written like above, but *not* like:

```
 1.1.1.11.1.1.21.1.1.3
```

How could I separate the contents of `contents` in newlines when downloading it?

Comment: @Teemu `<br>` in plain text?

Comment: Ouch, it was in `href`...

Comment: gives me this:  `1.1.1.1<br>1.1.1.21.1.1.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving newline characters in data:text URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532900/preserving-newline-characters-in-datatext-uri) (tested with your code, base64 encoding and using `\r\n` works)

Comment: @blex, tried  `a.href = `data:text;base64, ${content.replace('\n', '\r\n')}`;` but it gives me `Failed - Network Error`

Comment: @ssss Network error? Hmm, try actually encoding the string to base64 with the `btoa` function. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jwnvuysj/ . Oh, and if you replace `'\n'`, it's only going to replace the first line return. use regex instead: `/\n/g`. the `g` flag means "global" and will replace all line returns.